# ListResourceBundle and MissingResourceException

Tags: java

I'm working on a project that involves loading up a ResourceBundle. More explicitly, I've created a class that extends ListResourceBundle. The class is called Resources.java. It compiles fine and everything, but the MissingResourceException keeps popping up every time I try to load up the class:

All my source files are in package chapter31. When making this call with or without the "chapter31" in the string, always results in a MissingResourceException. My IDE is Eclipse. I've been playing around with this one problem for two days. I even tried changing the version of Eclipse. I'm at the end of my rope. What can I do in Eclipse to ensure that the getBundle() method can see the class. I don't know how it can miss it. It's in the same package! Please advise.

Alikas

```
package chapter31;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.util.ListResourceBundle;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Resources extends ListResourceBundle {
    Object contents[][];

    public Resources() {
        AudioClip clip = Applet.newAudioClip(getClass().getResource("/E31_10/audio/us.mid"));
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/E31_10/image/us.gif"));
        contents = new Object[3][2];
        contents[0] = new Object[] {"clip", clip};
        contents[1] = new Object[] {"icon", image};
        contents[3] = new Object[] {"delay", new Integer(68000)};
    }

    protected Object[][] getContents() {
        return contents;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ResourceBundle res = ResourceBundle.getBundle("chapter31.Resources");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The MissingResourceException is misleading here. Your problem may be caused by two other problems:

1. The resources in the following two lines cannot be found:

   > AudioClip clip =
   >   Applet.newAudioClip(getClass().getResource("/E31_10/audio/us.mid"));
   >       ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/E31_10/image/us.gif"));
2. If the first one is not the problem, there is a second problem:

   You have a wrong array index `contents[3]` which will cause `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and this will also cause the misleading MissingResourceException to be thrown. If you can find this exception in your exception stack trace, your problem is here. Change it to contents[2] will solve the problem.

**Note:** The reason you are seeing MissingResourceException is ultimately caused by the class loader cannot create an instance of the Resources class due to the problems pointed out above. If you had put the **contents** array initialization codes in a separate method instead of the constructor, you may not get this exception at the object initialization phase. Of course, other exceptions will pop out later when you try to call getObject method.

Comment: Thank you, thank you thank you!!!!!!!!. Well spotted Chris. Small thing but makes a huge difference. All work perfectly now :)

Comment: @MrQuestion: are you saying my (dragon66 not Chris) answer solved your problem? If so, please accept it as correct answer by checking the check mark

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to load a message properties file called "chapter31.Resources"? If so then in Eclipse you can try the below:

- Click on "Debug Configuration..."
- Find the launcher you are using to execute the main method for Resources
- Click on the Classpath tab
- Click on "User Entries" and then Click the "Advanced" button
- Select "Add External Folder" and choose the folder the "chapter31.Resources" .

ResourceBundle.getBundle() method is looking for the file in your classpath . if this file is not in your classpath it won't be able to find it.

The steps above adds the folder that "chapter31.Resources" to your classpath.

If this still does not work you can try passing the full path of the file to ResourceBundle.getResource().

Comment: hello thank you for answer. I tried, but still i get: exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name chapter31.Resources9, locale en_GB

Comment: You have to have a file named "chapter31.Resources" for this to work.  Try creating a file named this.  Values in this file must be of the format: key = value for each line.  The following 2 pages you may find useful.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/list.html http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.Control.html

Comment: Oh and you could also name the file "chapter31.Resources_en_GB"